# How to run multiple spiders in Scrapy (which use Selenium) from a single file main.py?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

When I try to run the parser through the terminal using the "scrapy crawl gpuParser" command, everything is parsed successfully. However, if I create a file main.py (in the same folder from which I ran the command) and will try to run the spiders through it (using CrawlerProcess) I'm not parsing anything and it looks like Selenium is not being used in this case. Can you tell me how to fix it?
Please don't judge me harshly, because this is my first time working with Scrapy and Python.

settings.py:

```
from shutil import which

SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('chromedriver')
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['--headless']  
  
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
     'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
     }

BOT_NAME = "Parser"

SPIDER_MODULES = ["Parser.spiders"]
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = "Parser.spiders"

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION = "2.7"
TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = "utf-8"
```

The file main.py:

```
from Parser.spiders.gpuParser import GpuparserSpider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


def main():
    settings = get_project_settings()
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl(GpuparserSpider)
    process.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The spider file:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest


class GpuparserSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "gpuParser"
    allowed_domains = ["citilink.ru"]
    custom_settings = {
        'FEEDS': {
            'gpu.json': {
                'format': 'json'
            }
        }
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://citilink.ru/catalog/videokarty"
        yield SeleniumRequest( url=url,
                               callback=self.parse )

    def parse(self, response):
        value = 0
        for gpu in response.css("div.app-catalog-1tp0ino.e1an64qs0 a"):
            value += 1
            yield {
                    "value": value,
                    "label": gpu.attrib["title"].split(",")[0].partition(' ')[2]
                  }
```

[What the files look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHgho.png)

I checked several times whether Selenium works, and everything works. I don't understand why it doesn't work in main.py .